# highlight listview item won't work properly

Tags: wpf, listview, styles, highlight, itemcontainerstyle

After i applied a custom `ItemContainerStyle` on my listView, **Highlighting** a listView's item won't work as it supposed to, it only works when the mouse is over the `ContentPresenter` of the item as you can see in the screenshots:

Original highlight (with no style applied):

[image]

highlight when custom ItemContainerStyle applied

[image]

highlight when custom ItemContainerStyle applied (mouse over `ContentPresenter`)

[image]

ListView Style:

```
    <Style x:Key="DetailStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="l:ListBoxSelector.Enabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource DetailViewStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="30" CellTemplate="{StaticResource columnIconDT}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" CellTemplate="{StaticResource columnNameDT}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Size"  Width="100" CellTemplate="{StaticResource columnSizeDT}"/>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

ItemContainerStyle :

```
<Style x:Key="DetailViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="ContextMenu.ContextMenuOpening" Handler="Item_ContextMenuOpening"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="Item_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-1"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource ContextMenuForItem}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                        <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="gridrowPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#33C1DEFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#41A5CDFF" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7DA2CE"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7DA2CE"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#97C1DEFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#A7A5CDFF" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFB4B4B4"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#7FE5E5E5" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#B2CCCCCC" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have replaced the default `ControlTemplate` of the `ListViewItem` with your own definition and that definition does not contain the elements that highlighted the item on mouse over.

The solution is simple... find the default `ControlTemplate` and update your `ControlTemplate` with the missing elements... I'm guessing, that you at least need the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` element from the original `ControlTemplate`.

You can find full details of the default `ControlTemplate` of the `ListViewItem` from the [ListView Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

Dude, if you are going to override part of any control's `ControlTemplate`, you do it like this:

First, copy the *whole* default `ControlTemplate` into *your* new `ControlTemplate` and ensure that it is working properly. Then, and *only* then, can you start to adjust the contents, checking each time that you add or remove a few things, whether it still works as expected.

This is a fail-safe method and only sloppy work on your side could stop it from working... give it a go.